# Ruby on rails extract line to pdf and convert

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf

I have a pdf file that contains:

first_name last_name and A2, B8, .... on every day of the month
A2 = 8am - 10am - store
B8 = 2pm - 8pm - workshop

I need to extract the user's line and convert A2, B8 ... to display on one page only the schedules in table form.

The user must be able to modify his table if there is a change, or return to the previous value if a solution has been found in the meantime.

Do you have an idea for a gem or a piece of code?

I'm not a ruby on rails expert but I'm not a beginner either.

Comment: This question really needs some Ruby code for context so we know what we're working with, and more importantly, working towards. At the absolute least, when you say "convert to" show us an example in Ruby of the desired output form.

Comment: I think he's looking or a gem that can extract data from the PDF, and populate a table in the database.  afterwards, I'm assuming he'll want to "parse" the data so that he can do database lookups grouping and sorting ... but I might be overthinking it

Comment: that's exactly what I want to do @jad

Comment: working with PDFs can be hard, it all depends on how the PDF was generated.  what looks like a table to us, with all the data in neat rows might well not be internally, the order that strings appear on the page is not related to the order they were added to the document.  there are "pdf_reader" gems, and "rtesseract" (if you need character recognition), but you might well find that you don't get consistent results.  you'll need to try it to work out if it will work for you